# Form validation with PHP not working

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I'm pretty new to PHP and I'm trying to validate a simple form with three input fields. For some reason i get nothing returned when i click the submit button while the fields are empty. I have been wrestling with this issue for hours now.

What I am trying to achieve is to get a error text next to the fields when they are empty/invalid.

Here is my HTML and PHP code.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table width="450px">
        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <label for="nimi">Nimi</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top"> 

            <td><input type="text" name="nimi"><span class="error"><?php echo $nimiVirhe;?></span></td>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <label for="sposti">SÃ¤hkÃ¶posti</label>

        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <td><input type="text" name="sposti"><span class="error"><?php echo $spostiVirhe;?></span></td>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <label for="palaute">Palaute</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <textarea  name="palaute" maxlength="1000" cols="30" rows="6"></textarea><span class="error"><?php echo $palauteVirhe;?> </span>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="LÃ¤hetÃ¤" name="submit">
        </td>
        </tr>


    </table>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$nimiVirhe = $spostiVirhe = $palauteVirhe = "";
$nimi = $sposti = $palaute = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["nimi"])) {
        $nimiVirhe = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $nimi = test_input($_POST["nimi"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nimi)) {
            $nimiVirhe = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["sposti"])) {
        $spostiVirhe = "Contact is required";
    } else {
        $sposti = test_input($_POST["sposti"]);
        if (!filter_var($sposti, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $spostiVirhe = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (trim($_POST["palaute"]) == "") {
        $palauteVirhe = "City is required";
    } else {
        $palaute = test_input($_POST["palaute"]);
    }
}


function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

I don't know what to try next.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. If the _boxes_ I assume you mean fields are empty then you wont see anything in them when you submit the form

Comment: you have paste php first and then html table, and also you forgot action in form

Comment: What i mean is that i am trying to get an error message to appear next to the fields IF the fields are empty.

Comment: Since your 'action' attribute is blank that means the form will post to itself.  Is your PHP code at the top of the page?

Comment: I have tested it and it works ok put the php code on top